# Update column, non distinct ID with secondary id?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
+-----+-----+------+----------+
| id  | num | text |  combo   |
+-----+-----+------+----------+
| 126 |   1 |   12 | 12,58,94 |
| 126 |   2 |   58 |          |
| 126 |   3 |   94 |          |
| 130 |   1 |   28 | 28,45,64 |
| 130 |   2 |   45 |          |
| 130 |   3 |   64 |          |
+-----+-----+------+----------+
```

I have this table, where the column "combo" is currently null.  I am trying to update it as such with data from "text" (from min value to max value in "num" and for each distinct id)

Any help formulating this query would be greatly appreciated, pardon my poor phrasing.

Comment: "combo" reflects what i would like to happen in the update query, but i am having an luck thus far....

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? If you are using SQL Server 2008 (or later version), you can using [window functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable(id INT,num INT,text INT,combo VARCHAR(100))
GO
INSERT INTO #MyTable
VALUES 
(126,1,12,NULL),
(126,2,58,NULL),
(126,3,94,NULL),
(130,1,28,NULL),
(130,2,45,NULL),
(130,3,64,NULL)
GO
```

**Query**

```
;With UpdateRecord
 AS
   (
   SELECT *  , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [text])
   FROM #MyTable
   ),
UpdateValues 
AS
(
 SELECT ID, Num,  STUFF(List.Numbers, 1 ,2 , '') Vals
           , rn2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [text])
 FROM #MyTable t CROSS APPLY 
                     (
                      SELECT ', ' + CAST([text] AS VARCHAR) [text()]
                      FROM #MyTable
                      WHERE id = t.id
                      FOR XML PATH('')
                      )List(Numbers)
)
UPDATE UpdateRecord  
SET combo = (SELECT TOP 1 Vals 
             FROM UpdateValues
             WHERE id = UpdateRecord.id AND rn = UpdateRecord.rn
             AND rn = 1)
```

**Result**

```
╔═════════╦═════╦══════╦════════════════╗
║     id  ║ num ║ text ║     combo      ║
╠═════════╬═════╬══════╬════════════════╣
║     126 ║   1 ║   12 ║     12, 58, 94 ║
║     126 ║   2 ║   58 ║     NULL       ║
║     126 ║   3 ║   94 ║     NULL       ║
║     130 ║   1 ║   28 ║     28, 45, 64 ║
║     130 ║   2 ║   45 ║     NULL       ║
║     130 ║   3 ║   64 ║     NULL       ║
╚═════════╩═════╩══════╩════════════════╝
```

Comment: Can't format to save life. Column name 'text()' contains an invalid XML identifier as required by FOR XML

Comment: on the execution of line:
SELECT ', ' + CAST([text] AS VARCHAR) [text()]

Comment: @user2124053 post your query what are you doing ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive cte:

```
declare @SourceTable TABLE
(
    id int, num int,textvalue varchar(255), combo varchar(255)
)
INSERT INTO @SourceTable(id, num, textvalue) VALUES
(126, 1, 12),(126, 2, 58),(126, 3, 94),(130, 1, 28),(130, 2, 45),(130, 3, 64)
```

Create a recursive cte that concatenates the values:

```
;with cte_ConcatenatedText(id, textvalue, num) AS
(
    SELECT id, textvalue, num  FROM @SourceTable WHERE num = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT st.id, cast(cte.textvalue + ',' + st.textvalue as varchar(255)), st.num
    FROM @SourceTable st
    INNER JOIN cte_ConcatenatedText cte ON cte.id =  st.id and cte.num = st.num -1
)
```

After that you can update the source table:

```
UPDATE @SourceTable SET combo = cte.textvalue
FROM @SourceTable st
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT id, textvalue,num FROM cte_ConcatenatedText) cte
ON cte.id = st.id and st.num = 1
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT id, MAX(num) AS num FROM @SourceTable group by id) maxNum
on maxNum.id = cte.id and maxNum.num = cte.num

SELECT * FROM @SourceTable
```

Result:

```
id  num textvalue   combo
126 1   12      12,58,94
126 2   58      NULL
126 3   94      NULL
130 1   28      28,45,64
130 2   45      NULL
130 3   64      NULL
```